# Creating a Column List based off Conditions of Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter

I have a dataset containing numbers relating to different years (below):

```
      2021_Sales     2022_Sales     2023_Sales     2024_Sales     2025_Sales     
0              0             19             36             35              0                
1             83             62              0              0              0
2              0              0              0              0             58
3            112              7              0              0              0
4              0              0              0              0             37
```

I want to create a column `Active Years` which lists the years where there are sales greater than 0. The resulting df will look like the below. I want the resulting column to be a list so I can then filter the dataset by year.

```
      2021_Sales     2022_Sales     2023_Sales     2024_Sales     2025_Sales        Active Years
0              0             19             36             35              0        2022,2023,2024 
1             83             62              0              0              0        2021,2022 
2              0              0              0              0             58        2025 
3            112              7              0              0              0        2021, 2022 
4              0              0              0              0             37        2025
```

I've tried various np.where and np.select methods and have been unable to find a solution.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df["Active Years"] = df.filter(regex=r"\d{4}_Sales").apply(
    lambda x: ",".join(x[x > 0].index.str.split("_").str[0]), axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   2021_Sales  2022_Sales  2023_Sales  2024_Sales  2025_Sales    Active Years
0           0          19          36          35           0  2022,2023,2024
1          83          62           0           0           0       2021,2022
2           0           0           0           0          58            2025
3         112           7           0           0           0       2021,2022
4           0           0           0           0          37            2025
```

---

Or if you want a list:

```py
df["Active Years"] = df.filter(regex=r"\d{4}_Sales").apply(
    lambda x: x[x > 0].index.str.split("_").str[0].tolist(), axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   2021_Sales  2022_Sales  2023_Sales  2024_Sales  2025_Sales        Active Years
0           0          19          36          35           0  [2022, 2023, 2024]
1          83          62           0           0           0        [2021, 2022]
2           0           0           0           0          58              [2025]
3         112           7           0           0           0        [2021, 2022]
4           0           0           0           0          37              [2025]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of each year where sales are greater than zero for each row in `df`.

```py
df['Active Years'] = [np.arange(2021, 2026)[np.array(i)] for i in (df > 0).values]
```